# Negative log10 transformation in R

Tags: r, math

I have a vector of p-values I want to perform a `-log10` transformation on. I'm aware of functions like `log2` and `log10` but can't seem to find anything on performing a negative log transformation. What I have found is not working. This is my current code:

```
x <- -log(dataTable$Pvalues, base = 10)
```

When executed, this gives me a vector with both numeric and infinite (`Inf`) values.

How can I correctly perform a transformation with `-log10` without getting infinite values?

Comment: It looks like you have zeros in the vector of p-values. You should remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know your data, but you could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
dataTable.1 <- dataTable %>%
  filter(Pvalues != 0)

x <- -log(dataTable.1$Pvalues, base = 10)
```